# Keeping up with the Jones'

Tags: hearthstone

Until the recent [TGT](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/The_Grand_Tournament) expansion, I had been doing reasonably well with a mage deck I created myself.
Since the expansion, I am have around a 50/50 win loss ratio, which is terrible.

What changes should I make to my deck to continue being a rush-style deck, but still be able to combat the newer cards?

[image]

Putting in [Dr. Boom](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Dr._Boom) seemed to help me if I got in to a medium length match, but I would rather have it over and done with by that point.

I don't mind dusting, but I can't afford all the Legendary cards.

I have too many cards to list, so I'll check my collection as people make suggestions.

Things to note:

- Completed [BRM](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Blackrock_Mountain)
- Opened a large number of packs (all expansions)
- Have all [basic cards](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Basic_card_list)

Comment: If you feel this question isn't suited for this stack let me know.

Comment: I think it's encouraged to have questions with a scope that could help other future searchers out. So as a suggestion, maybe rather than trying to find general advice that fits your specific collection, try picking out some representative examples of losses you're seeing now and ask for advice on how to respond to those?

Comment: As it currently is, the question is too broad to cover all the possibilities out there. I could generically answer, "Put an ooze in there to counter weapon classes" and still have it be viable. If you were to focus on this deck vs certain matchups IE. Control Warrior, Dragon Priest, Secret Paladin, etc. we'd have a better time trying to answer it.

Comment: Yeah I've voted down as too opinion based.

Comment: From a generic standpoint though, your knife juggler doesn't synchronize with your deck really. You don't have anything that summons multiple minions to take advantage of the knife juggles. The deck looks like a weaker mech mage build with a couple of different tech choices.

Comment: If you can find room for mechanical yeti, clockwork gnome, and a second tinkertown tech, they'll double synergize (mechs plus spare part spells to activate flamewaker.)

Comment: @walrus helmet I'll have a look at what I don't seem to be using.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like a fairly standard mech mage aggro list, except you're only running one copy of a lot of key cards and are running several that simply don't work in this deck. Putting in random cards because they seem like a good idea only makes your deck less reliable.

You're aiming for something like [this deck](http://www.hearthpwn.com/decks/141294-strifecros-mech-mage), though it is from pre-BRM so you have more options now, such as flamewaker.

Remove the following cards:

- Arcane Intellect- you're trying to play a fast aggro deck. Wasting an entire turn drawing cards slows you down and gives your opponent a chance to take control of the board or brings them one turn closer to summoning something you can't deal with.
- Vaporize and Mirror Entity- they're expensive and don't have an immediate effect. Duplicate and Mirror entity can be worth running, but only with Mad Scientist to get them into play for free.
- Knife Juggler- While he's an amazing card in Zoolock, Hunter, or Paladin, Mage doesn't have any way to summon multiple minions with a single card. He's also competing for slots with the other two mana mechs- that juggler could be an annoy-o-tron or another micro machine.

With the space you now have, add a second copy of any of the cheaper mechs. Annoy-o-trons or clockwork gnomes are also effective. Harvest golem is also a strong card because it is a mech that is very difficult to remove.

Comment: I've taken some of your advice about replacing some of the cards and I've gone straight to rank 14 so far. I'll make some more tweaks tomorrow.

Comment: Hoodlamic1: I'm not sure If this is right but to add on to what @Studoku said I think you can remove keyzan mystic and replace it with a spidertank. now keyzan has great value against secret decks like secret paladin but it dose not have consistent value in my opinion where as spidertank always has a good value. Good luck with your new deck!